# Using for loops in R to save 100 heatmaps

Tags: r

I am trying to create heatmaps using RStudio in a for loop. I would like to save it in the folder directly rather than displaying the graphs in the plots window. I want to know how to do this inside a loop.

This is the code I tried so far>
    a[[i]] is dataframe containing the values to be plotted

```
setwd("/home/coolgal2k/output/heatmaps/")
hm = NULL
for (i in 1:100){
hm.900[[i]] <- heatmap.2(a[[i]], 
                     dendrogram="none", Rowv=F,Colv=F, 
                     col=bluered(256), scale="none", key=T, 
                     density.info="none", main=paste0("Heatmap of Z-scores","[[i]])", 
                     cexRow=0.7, cexCol=0.7, trace="none", symm=F, symbreaks=T, symkey=T) 
dev.off()
}
```

When I try to do this:

I get error saying that unexpected "}" in:
I checked for all formatting in the code, it is fine!

Please help!

Comment: You're missing a closing quote or a closing parentheses somewhere in all your ellipses.  If you want us to help debug, please include all the code as well as the package name you're using.

Comment: @Justin: Just edited with the entire code! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paste command has the closing `)` inside the quote. Its even colored wrong by the SO highlighter.  If you're not already, I strongly suggest getting a [good editor](http://www.rstudio.com/) that does this similar syntax highlighting for you.

To save separate images, you can open a separate device and close it in each loop

```
for ... {
    png(paste(filename, I))
    heatmap.2(...)
    dev.off()
}
```

Or better, open a single device, and r do the work

```
png( "filename%02d")
for ...{
    heatmap.2(...)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin. I got to know where exactly you are pointing out. I would like to know how to save each of them in a folder inside this loop.

Comment: @coolgal2k that is a separate and unrelated question.  Please accept this as answered and ask another using all the code you supplied above.  Also, please make it [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  However, to save them, you need to open a device for each image inside your loop...

Comment: My question in the first instance was to know how to save each plot in a folder inside a loop

Comment: Touche.  Answer edited